# Using random library to guess number (Python)

Tags: loops, python-3.x, random

```
#This program generates random number
#user enters guess
#progam tells user higher, lower or correct based on user input.
import random

def main():
    # Get a random number.
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    user_guess = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 100: "))
    userguess = guess(user_guess, number)
    print(userguess)


def guess(num1, num2):
    if num1 > num2:
        return("Lower")
    elif num1 < num2:
        return("Higher")
    else:
        return("Correct")
```

main()

I can get the program to generate a random number, then display higher or lower, but not as again. It is supposed to ask again until it hits the random and then displays 'correct'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop to keep prompting until the correct answer is guessed, `while(True)` keeps going until a `break;` is reached. Try something like this.

```
def guess(num):
    while(True):
        user_guess = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 100: "))
        if user_guess > num:
            print("Lower\n")
        elif user_guess < num:
            print("Higher\n")
        else:
            print("Correct")
            break;
```

This will repeatedly ask user for numbers untill they are correct replace your main method with the following

```
def main():
    # Get a random number.
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    guess(number)
```

Edit: replaced true with True

Comment: Thank you. It crashes with the error NameError: global name 'true' is not defined

Comment: sorry replace with `True` (uppercase T)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Much appreciated. I'd offer you coffee, but im out of cream.

Comment: Your welcome, i recommend adding a flag to exit if the user wants to quit. something like `if user_guess == -1: break;`